# Why React native app is Too slow in comparison with expo

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, facebook, expo

I was Trying to build an app using react-native app.
but the app was running very slow like if i click or tap on any button it takes a around 1-2 seconds to perform basic function
and if i built the same thing using expo it works fine.
Can some please help me out why react native app is behaving like this.
[My react Native-App video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Y8jQRS8wrUcoTyH39)

My react Native-App video:https://photos.app.goo.gl/Y8jQRS8wrUcoTyH39

[My expo app video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/7Ezq3tErTS4aLL1GA)

My Expo react Native App Video: https://photos.app.goo.gl/7Ezq3tErTS4aLL1GA

I tried all possible methods to make react native faster like using memo and callable methods.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your app? It makes sense to try to use React DevTools to see what's going on with the JS / UI threads and see what's actually causing the slagginesh.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using native-base there an issue her : visit https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4302

Comment: Please do not post link only answers